# Xcode 11 GM 1 & 2 - Size classes not working in nib

Tags: xcode, ios13, xcode11

Ever since Xcode 11 GM has been released we have a problem with both versions 1 & 2.

We have a collection view cell that has different constraints activated using size class variations in the storyboard.

When we run the app on iOS13, the variations are respected and work as intended but if we run the app on iOS12 and bellow the collection view cell is stuck in whatever setup we are using in the storyboard preview.

If we switch to "preview as" and pick a Phone device then the tablet layout appears broken and vice versa.

Are there any known workaround? (besides not working with storyboards)